# Ansible resolving logical comparison `1 < 1` to true in a loop item test despite filtering/casting to int

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x

I'm running a play against a number of servers where the first task performs a sql query to get the schema version for a database. The query returns `"1"` (string) for instance when the schema version is 1. This is the structure of the response...

```
ok: [server.tld] => {
    "db_result": {
        "changed": false,
        "executed_queries": [
            "SELECT `value` FROM `registry` WHERE `setting` = 'schema_version'"
        ],
        "failed": false,
        "query_result": [
            [
                {
                    "value": "1"
                }
            ]
        ],
        "rowcount": [
            1
        ]
    }
}
```

In the next task I test to see if the schema version returned is less than the current version... in this case also `1` (int) but after a future upgrade we would test against `2` (int) which would cause all servers to run the patch that still return `1`. I use the Jinja filter `| int` to cast to integer for a proper comparison.

```
  - name: Copy schema update SQL file
    copy: src=roles/db/files/{{ item.src }} dest=/tmp/{{ item.src }}
    when: item.when
    loop:
      - src: schema_changes_v1.sql 
        when: "{{ db_result.query_result[0][0]['value'] | int }} < 1"
```

The problem is that even though the logical comparison is `when: 1 < 1` which should resolve to false, it's still proceeding with the item in the loop rather than skipping to the next one....

```
changed: [server.tld] => (item={'src': 'schema_changes_v1.sql', 'when': '1 < 1'})
```

Why??

Ansible 2.12.2

Comment: `{{ db_result.query_result[0][0]['value'] | int }} < 1` === the literal string `1 < 1`; you want `when: "{{ db_result.query_result[0][0]['value'] | int < 1}}` in your loop.

Comment: And if your first run should run the copy task when the result of your database call is `1`, then what you really want is `when: "{{ db_result.query_result[0][0]['value'] | int <= 1 }}`

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Thanks for catching the literal comparison, that ended up it! As for the version, it is indeed `<1` because I only want it to run if the version returned is LESS than the current version, which in this case is `1`. But then when I make the next schema change, the version will be 2 so I want any machine that either hasn't received any update or any at v1, but not those that are already at v2. I see where the confusion is, but It's only because I didn't have any schema versioning before this and the 1st update is being called v1 rather than v2.

Comment: You might want to look into the `version` test if your version follows semversion.

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/version_test.html

Comment: Thanks @β.εηοιτ.βε, Didn't know about that function! In this case I'm only using a simple int, but I have other uses for this that will come in quite handy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition in `when` is evaluated [as it's already within the curly braces](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#id3).

**Edited:**
But I didn't notice the most important thing in your example. The condition you're referring to is set as the value of `when` key within the loop element - that means that it's evaluated as a string first. And a non-empty string in a real `when` evaluates to `true` - that's the reason why you task gets executed each time.

So, simply put **the whole string** into the curly braces so that you get a boolean instead of a string:

```yaml
  - name: Copy schema update SQL file
    copy: src=roles/db/files/{{ item.src }} dest=/tmp/{{ item.src }}
    when: item.when
    loop:
      - src: schema_changes_v1.sql 
        when: "{{ db_result.query_result[0][0]['value'] | int < 1 }}"
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion and it's still showing as changed... `changed: [server.tld] => (item={'src': 'schema_changes_v1.sql', 'when': 'db_result.query_result.0.0.value | int < 1'})`. Tried both the bracketed and direct method for the value variable, which is why it's in the format `db_result.query_result.0.0.value` in the result.

Comment: I've even tried setting the `1` to `0`, but it's still resolving to true for some reason. I know that everything is indeed being processed to because I have a counter increment in the SQL file for testing and it's increasing the counter on each run.

Comment: @oucil I was on a bus and didn't notice the real problem. I corrected my answer - please check.

Comment: That did it, thank you! Sometimes just needs another set of eyes :)