# Ansible - can I condense multiple tasks into one using dual loops and the correct data structure

Tags: ansible, infrastructure-as-code

I have the following data and conditions:

```
1. file_1 when condition_1
2. file_2 when condition_2
3. file_3 when condition_3
4. file_4 when condition_4
```

Each of conditions1-4 are made up of two sub-conditions. Condition_1 = (condition_a and condition_b) and so on. I'm thinking, though, that I can 'pre-compound' conditions_a and so on such that all I have to deal with are 1-4.

```
when:
  - condition_a [an ansible fact]
  - condition_b [another ansible fact]
```

I'm currently using four tasks for 1., 2., 3., 4. like this:

```
  - name: task 1
    copy:
      src: file_x
      dest: /some/place
    when:
      - condition_x
```

There must be a way to construct this using loops if I assemble the files/conditions into an appropriate data structure. Two lists, two loops? Some sort of dictionary structure. The 'items' would seem to be part of the 'file' and 'when' fields and I'm not quite sure how to deal with this. Should I be using the zip filter?

As you can see, my thinking is jumbled with a few concepts (it's still early Ansible days for me) and I'd like some help calrifying this all. Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

Comment: "_There must be a way to construct this ..._", most probably yes. "_using loops if I assemble the files/conditions into an appropriate data structure_" as for my understanding or how I interpret this, it looks like a truth table, so no. "_Any suggestions would be most appreciated_", Since it has nothing to do with Ansible at all, but with boolean logic and truth table, I recommend to use that approach.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, the code in https://stackoverflow.com/a/78036930/16417367 might inspire you. There is a list of dicts, each of them contains the file path and the condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can iterate over a list of dicts - something like this should do the trick:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    files_and_conditions:
      - src: file_x
        dest: dest_x
        condition: "{{ condition_x }}"
      - src: file_y
        dest: dest_y
        condition: "{{ condition_y }}"

- name: task 1
  copy:
    src: "{{ item.src }}"
    dest: "{{ item.dest }}"
  when: item.condition
  loop: "{{ files_and_conditions }}"
```

Note that the `condition` should be evaluated as a boolean so you have to put the whole condition between the curly braces - see the linked question for details.

Comment: Thank you so much, I can definitely see this working. That's very helpful to know about the Boolean. One thing: let's say the destination was a variable, one of a list of items. I could presumably add an extra row in each of the loops "-dest: place_a". However I'm wondering, is there an alternative which could have me looping through a pre-defined list of destinations - and sources too.  I'm thinking something like: loop: "{{ src | zip(dest) | list }}" with item.0 and item.1 in src and dest. Then how to integrate with the conditionality?

Comment: I guess the challenge is each file needs a specific condition assigning to it. The zip construct is a single line: can one map a specific condition to each logical output of the loop plus how can that, in turn, be mapped to the 'when' field?

Comment: Sure you can do that - I didn't define the variable and put the list directly into `loop` for the sake of simplicity. I edited my answer to do that. I think `zip` might work too, but using keys instead of indexes is much more intuitive and understandable.

Comment: I agree. There's value is keeping the code readable and this should not be sacrificed for brevity. A question about the "condition": as written, it equates to "true" is that right. For some reason it doesn't seem to be working. For example, one of the conditions is (ansible_distribution == Debian or ansible_distribution = Ubuntu). If I try copying to a vm running almalinux with that condition in place it still proceeds.

Comment: One other question if I may: why use "set_fact" rather than define the info in vars?

Comment: _rather than define the info in vars_ - Haha, I expected that question! :) In this particular case, I just wanted to indicate that it could be set somewhere long before the subject task. But in general there are multiple differences covered in the documentation, also the behavior depends on where exactly the variables are defined.

Comment: _one of the conditions is (ansible_distribution == Debian or ansible_distribution = Ubuntu). If I try copying to a vm running almalinux with that condition in place it still proceeds._ - that might be a topic for a separate question (that most likely already has an answer on SO). I'm not familiar with Alma Linux so I don't know what distribution would it indicate. But I suppose that you had to use `==` in both conditions and quote the distribution names to make it work. Otherwise it might be evaluated as a non-empty string that is `true` as boolean.

Comment: I will check the documentation to understand more about variable precedence and so on. Thanks for your extremely helpful input!